# PHPUnit data provider error

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

So I just started using PHPUnit and I'm writing tests for a very simple library. It only consists of two classes so I figured it would be great place to start so I can get the hang of how Unit Testing works.

I made first class tests without any problems, but second one gives me a headache because I just can't figure out whats wrong with this. It seems to be some error with my data provider.

```
<?php

use PIFlex\Roulette\Roulette;

class RouletteTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $roulette;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->roulette = new Roulette();
    }

    /*
     * @dataProvider addItemDataProvider
     */
    public function testAddItem($item)
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(
            'PIFlex\Roulette\Roulette',
            $this->roulette->addItem($item, 1)
        );
    }

    public function addItemDataProvider()
    {
        return array(
            array("string"),
            array(1),
        );
    }
}
```

It throws me the following error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) RouletteTest::testAddItem
Missing argument 1 for RouletteTest::testAddItem()

/home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexRoulette/test/PHPUnit/Roulette/RouletteTest.php:22

FAILURES!
Tests: 12, Assertions: 11, Errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have wrong annotation comment. It should started with "**", so just change:

```
/*
 * @dataProvider addItemDataProvider
 */
```

into:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider addItemDataProvider
 */
```

Comment: Good catch. Missed that one.

Comment: Wait, what, why? This worked, thanks. Seems like a kind of strange requirement.

Answer (score 0):

*... expanding on [@Cyprian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14426364/934739) ...*

The [PHPUnit documentation Appendix  on annotations](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.annotations.html) notes that

> An annotation is a special form of syntactic metadata that can be added to the source code of some programming languages. While PHP has no dedicated language feature for annotating source code, the usage of tags such as `@annotation arguments` in documentation block has been established in the PHP community to annotate source code. In PHP documentation blocks are reflective: they can be accessed through the Reflection API's `getDocComment()` method on the function, class, method, and attribute level. Applications such as PHPUnit use this information at runtime to configure their behaviour. — [PHPUnit documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.annotations.html)

The `getDocComment()` reflection is available for:

- [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)
- [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionfunctionabstract.getdoccomment.php)
- [`ReflectionProperty`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionproperty.getdoccomment.php)

And while it isn't documented that two asterisk are required, it is noted in the comments section, [`ReflectionClass::getDocComment`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php#99938), and [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getDocComment`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionfunctionabstract.getdoccomment.php#94591).

**Resources**

- [PHP Reflection Documentation](http://php.net/manual/book.reflection.php)